# jQuery on change dropdown call web service to load options

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a dropdown list and a variable amount of options (in the form of checkboxes and text inputs).

What I want to achieve is onchange value of the dropdown list, call a web service and load the various options below it. I know roughly I have to use jQuery's onchange event and have Ajax load the markup into the div.

But how exactly do I achieve that?

I am using Bootstrap 3, and some of my form code is below. I am not sure how to write my Javascript or Ajax part, though.

**Dropdown list**

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBranch" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Branch</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="resBranch">
          <?php
            // print all branch name
            // if is same as merchantID, mark as selected
            foreach($branchesArray as $branch) {
              if($branch['merchantID'] == $merchantID) {
                echo "<option selected>" . $branch['name'] . "</option>";
              } else {
                echo "<option>" . $branch['name'] . "</option>";
              }
            }
          ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Options**

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Options</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">

        <?php
        foreach ($featuresArray as $feature) {
        ?>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $feature['customValue']; ?>">
              <?php echo $feature['customValue']; ?>
            </label>
          </div>
        <?php
        } // end foreach
        ?>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send an ajax request with the currently selected form option to a php web service which returns the html to add to the form. 
The js could look something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
   $('select').change(function () {
      $.get('ajax.php?option=' + $('select').val(), function(data) {
          if(data == "error")
          {
              //handle error
          }
          else {
              $('div.ajax-form').append(data); //create an element where you want to add 
                                               //this data
          }
      });
   });
 });
```

The php might look like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['option'])) {
    if($_GET['option'] == 1)
    {
        //echo form data for option one here 
    }

    elseif($_GET['option'] == 2)
    {
        //echo form options for option two here 
    }

    elseif($_GET['option'] == 3)
    {
        //echo form options for option two here 
    }

    //other options here

    else
    {
        echo "error"; //select value not correct
    }
}
```